# Loading html within static asset in WebViewX

Tags: flutter, mobile, webview

To be efficient, I have to load some static content and some dynamically fetched content.

My flutter main uses:

```
return WebViewX(
      key: const ValueKey('webviewx'),
      initialContent: initialContent,
      initialSourceType: SourceType.html,
      height: screenSize.height,
      width: screenSize.width,
      onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
        webviewController = controller;
        _setHtml();
      },
      mobileSpecificParams: const MobileSpecificParams(
        androidEnableHybridComposition: true,
      ),
    );

// ...
void _setHtml() {
    webviewController.loadContent(
      'assets/myjsfile.html',
      SourceType.html,
      fromAssets: true,
    );
  }
```

This loads a html file which executes some static javascript and then calls
`<script src="http://localhost:3000"></script>`.

My localhost serves some valid code.

Question: Why does this work on the chrome web emulator but not on mobile?